# Hacer un SavePoint, Rollback y Commit de Oracle en django, (Python 1.8.7)

Tags: python, sql, django, oracle

Quisiera hacer un savepoint, un rollback y un commit de Oracle en una view. Por ejemplo

```
def ejemploview(request):
  if request.method =='POST':
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
      #Aqui quisiera hacer el equivalente a savepoint save; en Oracle
      ...
      ...
      if i>0:
       #Aqui quisiera hacer el equivalente a rollback save; en Oracle
       #Aqui quisiera hacer el equivalente a commit; en Oracle
      else:
        #Aqui quisiera hacer el equivalente a commit; en Oracle
```

Me preguntaba si existia algo como el **cursor.execute()** para estos casos

Comment: en efecto existe el llamado raw sql donde ejecutas tu consulta o query: cursor.execute("SELECT id, parent_id FROM test LIMIT 2")....

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/